# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::RetrySet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq in one of my projects. Now I need to clear a queue,
the `RetrySet`, to be more specific.

Following [this page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Console-commands) from Sidekiq's Github manual, this should work:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
>> Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear
NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::RetrySet
```

But it doesn't. Sidekiq itself seems to be loaded:

```
>> Sidekiq
=> Sidekiq
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Using Sidekiq version 3.3.4

Comment: Hey Flip, could you please add the sidekiq version you are using?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the rails server since you added the sidekiq gem?

Comment: Added the version in OP.  Restarting the server didn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need to require the api library explicitly.

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
```

See this for more info https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1732

See https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L612

The inheritance explaination

```
class SortedSet
 ...

 def clear
 ...
 end
end

class JobSet < SortedSet
  ...
end

class RetrySet < JobSet
  ...
end
```

---

However, In my rails console it worked without needing me to require the library. It was already required. see

```
> require 'sidekiq/api'
=> false
```

I use Sidekiq `4.0.1`

```
> Sidekiq::VERSION
=> "4.0.1"
```